# What are common reasons that dogs beg?

Tags: dogs, behavior

My dog ate an hour ago and is now in sitting front of me, begging. I let him outside and he immediately went to go pee, but when he came back inside he started begging again. What could he be begging for?

Some common reasons are for:

- food
- attention
- to use the bathroom

What else could he be begging for and would there be a way to differentiate begging for each of these needs?

Comment: How often is his begging rewarded with food or attention?

Comment: I give my dog food when I'm eating. He does not beg with his paws when I'm feeding him.  Out of the blue he was begging with his paws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to figure it out is to stand up and see if your dog will lead you somewhere. When my dog would beg I would stand up and ask repeatedly "what do you want?" in a positive tone, then start walking to see what direction he will go to. They're pretty smart and will lead you to what they want or start playing with you if they want to play.

Another reason you haven't listed is to find a toy they lost, my grand-mothers dog will cry and lead her to where the toy is stuck or hidden.